Can an unmarried heterosexual couple share the same room in Doha?
Can an unmarried heterosexual couple share the same room in Doha?
I have found no mention of such restriction in government related travel advice site, only warning about avoid public display of affection, but other sites claim that some hotel can flat out refuse checking in unless they see valid proof of marriage, or that the entire trip can become far less pleasant if the unmarried status becomes known.

Technically unmarried couples are not allowed to stay in the same room but I think this is restricted to Qatari nationals. Anecdotally it's certainly not enforced for foreigners and some hotel specifically mention that it is allowed.  (e.g. https://movenpick.accor.com/en/middle-east/qatar/doha/hotel-doha/faqs.html).
There is also anecdotal evidence that even same-sex couples are allowed (https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/qatar-airways-privilege-club/2111215-doh-8hrs-layover-unmarried-couple-marriage-certificate-needed-hotel.html)
I've certainly never been asked for proof of marriage at check in but then again, we are married and have the same last name.

I think that the same name is key.  I once shared a room in Egypt with a woman I was traveling with (and we were simply traveling and not in any relationship), and it took some convincing of the staff at a hotel that we were related because of a lack of same last name.  We settled on that we were siblings.

Not sure how relevant that is but Movenpick is a Swiss company. So I would assume they will enforce the local law but otherwise are probably not too keep to impose restrictions of local moral standards.

I must say that Movenpick's answer on that topic in the FAQ you linked to is peculiar to say the least. The FAQ question: "Do couples staying in the same room at Mövenpick Hotel West Bay Doha require a marriage certificate?". The answer: "Mövenpick Hotel Doha is equipped with an outdoor swimming pool and jacuzzi area." (at least this is what I see on 2024-04-15) (this is the same answer as the next one - this time about pools and such). EDIT: I took a screenshot just in case: https://imgur.com/a/FzEepAb :)

@WoJ Any hotel that has a swimming pool and jacuzzi area clearly allows couples to stay in the same room.  Duh.

@WoJ Based on this FAQ item, I would guess they are not allowed or prefer not to say that a marriage certificate is not required. Their answer is quite diplomatic and gives them a chance to deny that they do not focus on this topic in their daily operations.

@WoJ:  Check the question "If I am travelling with my girlfriend to Mövenpick Hotel Doha, will we be able to stay in the same room?" the answer that I'm seeing is "Yes, unmarried couples are permitted to stay in the same room at Mövenpick Hotel Doha as long as they do not belong to the Qatari Nationality."

Well, I think what I was referring to jokingly got lost in translation. What I meant was that to the question "can people stay together", the FAQ answers "we have a swimming pool". This is obviously a mistake in copy-paste (this is the answer to the next FAQ, so there are two identical responses) and I found it funny, that's all. @Yakk got it right but I am afraid that I was not clear enough.

Ahhhh, you mean Hilmar that you see the proper answer? Look at the screenshot I linked above (https://imgur.com/a/FzEepAb) -- this is what I see in my browser :)
